# Shell Scripting: get unique items in a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The question is based on the function **uniq** unless you have some other suggestion.

I have a file which has only one column with n number of rows, and contains redundant names of items randomly.

I have tried command **uniq filename>filename2** to get the unique items in filename2... but it doesn't work. I still get the same list.

Any suggestions as to how I can tackle this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sort -u filename > filename2

Answer (score 3):

Try `sort -u`. `uniq` only filters out repeated lines, not duplicate lines spread out over the input.